# Подскажите удаленное видеонаблюдение с открытым кодом интернет-сервера?

Tags: администрирование, видео

**Глоссарий:**

Видеосервер - программа, которая записывает видео с камер, например, магазина.

Клиент - программа для просмотра данных с Видеосервера с другого компьютера. Если компьютер в том же магазине, то по локальной сети. Если компьютер в другом месте, то через интернет.

Интернет-сервер - грубо говоря, сайт, который позволяет Клиенту подключаться к Видеосерверу через интернет без использования VPN и статических IP. Интернет-сервер может иметь два типа реализации: облако или ретранслятор. Облако - данные хранятся в Интернете. Ретранслятор - данные прогоняются через интернет-сервер не сохраняясь на нем.

**Что требуется?**

Нужен проект с открытым исходным кодом (бесплатный), где:

1. Присутствовал бы Интернет-сервер.
2. Присутствовала бы возможность поднять свой такой Интернет-сервер.

Как еще один вариант формулировки вопроса - open source аналог iVideon.

Comment: Если честно, я вообще ничего не понял. О каких «облаке» и «ретрансляторе» речь? Чем «видеосервер» отличается от «интернет-сервера»? Есть что-нибудь почитать про терминологию, которую вы используете?

Comment: Нухз, под такую терминологию тогда подходит самый обычный ZoneMinder — видеосервер (пишет видео с камер), клиент (в данном случае это браузер), интернет-сервер (ибо подключаемся к нему по интернету через браузер), одновременно и облако (может сохранять записи у себя), и ретранслятор (прогоняет данные через себя, сохраняя или нет — смотря как настроено), исходники открыты

Comment: Короче. Есть сервер, к которому клиент может подконнектится по веб сокетам и получать фото с камер каждый небольшой промежуток времени. Реализовывайте :)

Comment: Да, но только чтобы попасть на этот видеосервер нужен статический IP. Тут речь о другом. Мы имеем в интернете сервер, который выступает в роли связующего звена Клиента и Видеосервера. В iSpy оно назыввается так: http://www.ispyconnect.com/userguide-connecting.aspx

Comment: Вебсокеты, да, как один из вариантов реализации. Реализовать-то можно) Но вдруг оно уже есть, зачем изобретать велосипед тогда?

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что [вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)